# Конвертация кодировки текста в PHP

Tags: php, строки, utf-8, кодировка

Есть две переменные типа string:
1) задана вручную в php коде ($date1="14 июня"),
2) "содрана" при помощи cURL+phpQuery c удаленной страницы ($date2)

У первой пременной длинна строки 7, а у второй 12. Как конвертировать $date2 в точно такой же "формат" как и $date1?
Я так понимаю вторая пременна содержит мультибайтовый контент.

```
echo $date1; //выводит 14 июня
echo $date2; //выводит 14 июня
echo strlen($date1); //выводит 7
echo strlen($date2); //выводит 12
echo mb_detect_encoding($date1) //выводит UTF-8
echo mb_detect_encoding($date2) //выводит UTF-8
```

Comment: а кто-то задал вопрос "как правильно определить длинну строки"? Это я и так знал. Задача перевести мультибайтовую строку в обынчую (синглбайт)

Comment: честно говоря, я был на этой странице, но не совсем понял из какой в какую переводить. Обе вроде UTF-8 (если верить mb_detect_encoding), не буду же переводить ютф8 в ютф8.

Comment: нарыл в интернете `phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($content, "windows-1251");` вы настраивали в своем скрипте кодировку, с которой работает phpquery? обязательно сделайте trim() нет ли у вас каких либо преобразований между этими строками?

Answer (score 0):

[Уникод имеет множество представлений](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4#.D0.90.D0.BB.D0.B3.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BC.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.B8.D0.B7.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D0.B8) если говорить о бинарном виде. Привести всё к одному виду можно, например, так:

```
$output = Normalizer::normalize($input);
```

Этот класс содержится в [модуле php-intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).